# MySQL table exporting and importing using a file - without phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, import, export, backup

It'd be nice if I could request a backup file (such as a .sql or .csv) for my MySQL table through my site, so I would be able to 'reset' the table in case anything goes wrong. These two actions, exporting and importing, are explained [here](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/mysql_export.htm), but in my case it'd be much better if this could be done via a web interface of some kind, without accessing phpMyAdmin directly. Is this possible? If so, what PHP functions should I be taking a look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this MySQL doc page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) and look for the `INTO OUTFILE` option that allows you to write your results directly to a file without even reading them from PHP.

Comment: This looks promising, though I have no idea how to specify the path.
SELECT a,b,a+b INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'    is given as an example, but where does that create the file? Does it start at the root of my server or is it relative?

Comment: That's an absolute filesystem path.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the backup file, I'd like to generate a link to it so it can be downloaded. At the moment though, I'm not sure if it has even succesfully created the file (I'm using '/path-to-public_html/backupfile.txt'). How do I go about this, how do I know if all my permissions are set right?

Answer (score 1):

Use mysqldump

```
mysqldump -u username -ppassword -h hostname database_name > db_name_backup.sql
```

[Mysqldump documentation is here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html)

Comment: Will I have to use the System(); function for this? Sound like something I wouldn't have access to, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: How you want to run this?. Php ?. You can just write a shell script and run it like any other script.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to run it via PHP.

Comment: Then you need to run it in system. As backup method mysqldump is better as this method also keeps schema with it.